# Appium : Maven : Unable to compile project through cmd

Tags: maven, cmd, appium

I am unable to compile my `appium` test project.

> ```
> My system :windows 8.1 with 64bit
> Appium : 1.4.16
> Java version : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
> java version "1.8.0_111"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
> Maven version : 
> Maven home: C:\Users\test\Downloads\ReqSoftwares\apache-maven-3.3.9
> Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
> Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
> OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
> ```

Here is my `Pom.xml` :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Test for Application</description>
    <name>Test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Commands used:

```
mvn clean package
mvn install
```

Comment: `mvn` is a batch-file, right? if so, try `call mvn ...`...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Java home is not set to jdk. It has jre appended to it.